# Move towards a goal

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

What are other scripts to make an object move to a goal? Right now I'm using the `Vector3.Lerp` method. This works, but the moving gameobject slows down the closer it gets to its goal. I don't wont this to happen. It has to move straight to the goal without slowing down.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is just to work out the direction it should head in and then move at a constant speed in that direction:

```
function Update() {
    var dir = target - transform.position;
    dir.Normalize();
    transform.position += dir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

You'd have to make it a little more complicated than that so that it doesn't overshoot on the final frame, but this should give you a crude approximation of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

It should do exactly what you want.